# Is there a way to sort by time remaining in the Auction House?

Tags: diablo-iii

I have been trying to arrange the time remaining column in the auction house from least time remaining to most time hoping to score a good deal, however I find that I can't click on it.

Does anyone know if this is something Blizzard will allow us to do? It seems like a huge oversight to me.

Comment: Question should be close as there is no longer an auction house for diablo 3.

Comment: @z- Question should not be closed. See [this answer](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/8451/50582) to your own meta question about D3.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of the 1.04 patch on 8/21/2012, you can sort by time remaining by clicking on the column header in the table.

Comment: You are all over it.  Way to update!